# time series prediction with several independent variables using RNNs and Keras

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I came across [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/17099/adding-features-to-time-series-model-lstm) excellent question and answer by Adam Sypniewski. Here method of using RNNs (e.g. LSTMs and GRUs) for predicting time series where the dependent variable depends on several independent variables. Just wondering, is anyone aware of some Keras code for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please go through this tutorial:

https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/

The author focuses on LSTM-RNNs with explicit instructions on how to re-shape your dataset into the format that Keras requires, which can be **VERY** tricky if not properly understood.

Answer (score 1):

From the same question you mentioned, you will find an interesting [link](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) to Keras documentation. If you navigate to **Multi-input and multi-output models** you'll find an example code that does exactly this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See
. Multiple Input and Output Models

https://machinelearningmastery.com/keras-functional-api-deep-learning/