# One-hot encode multi-class multi-label sequences

Tags: time-series, encoding, sequence-to-sequence

Suppose I want to build a timeseries where each timestep is represented by a categorical array: the encoded sequences look like `[[2, 0, 5],[3, 1, 4],..]` and each entry has a different number of possible values (categories). 
For example the first entry has 0-3 values, the second 0-1 and so on...

I want to train an LSTM model in order to predict **the next timestep**. So I defined a one hot encoding of each entry by means of the maximum number of classes:

For example `[2, 0, 5]` becomes

```
[[0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.],
[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.],
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]
```

Unfortunately this kind of representation raises the error

> ValueError: Invalid shape for y: (1, 3, 5)

I have three questions:

1. Is it possible to pass a **3d y target** to Keras?
2. Should I define a **single one-hot encoding** which combines all the possible triplets of categorical values instead? The problem is that in this case I would lose the correlation between the occurrences of the labels in the same category, because each possible combination of labels would become independent from the other ones.
3. Should I **only one-hot encode the target y** or also the input X?

Answer (score 2):

You may need to try [cat2vec](https://www.kaggle.com/classtag/cat2vec-powerful-feature-for-categorical) which converts categorical features into vector representation using Word2Vec approach. Check also this link for [multi-feature inputs into LSTM](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/17099/adding-features-to-time-series-model-lstm).

For the target y, one-hot is a better technique for NN-based models.